# Remove Ubuntu 12.10 without reformat?

Tags: uninstall

I was recently told that using lubuntu or xubuntu would be better for my old machine than just plain old ubuntu. Would i use wubi to uninstall ubuntu 12.10 and then cancel the install? thanks!

Comment: Did you install using Wubi or live CD?

Comment: I installed using Wubi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is really no need to uninstall. You can simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or open Terminal. Log in there with your username and password.

Now, on the terminal, type:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

to get Xubuntu, or

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

to install Lubuntu.

You will be prompted for your password. Enter it and press Enter. If will not be shown, not even asterisks. Let the commend finish(it may take quote a while as it downloads packages). You can then pick the desktop environment as follows:

When you get to the logon screen, there will be a little white circle to the right of your username. Click it, and you will get a choice of environments. IIRC once you pick one it will remain until you change it.

Screenshot below:

Click the circle:
[image]

and select the DE you want:

[image]

Comment: I would do that if i could, but when I'm booting, all I get is a mouse and a black screen behind it.

Comment: @KyleHamblett Can you still try the key combo after giving it a few minutes to "boot"?